# If $f(x)=\int_0^x x^2 \sin {t^2}~dt $, find $f'(x)$.

Tags: calculus

Stumbled with this problem

> If $f(x)=\int_0^x x^2 \sin {t^2}~dt $, find $f'(x)$.

How do you solve problems like this?

Comment: Pull out the $x^2$, then use the product rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: OP: Do you mean $\sin^2{t}$ or $\sin(t^2)$? If you mean the latter then I don't believe it's expressible in elementary functions.

Comment: It is the latter @Oliver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: $f(x) = x^2 \cdot g(x)$, where $g$ is the integral after the $x^2$  has been taken out.

So $f'(x) = (x^2)'\cdot g(x) + g'(x) \cdot(x^2)$ by the product rule.

The derivative of $g(x)$ is exactly [the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part).

---

BONUS: What if the upper limit of the integral is $3x$?

Comment: What do you mean by 'take x^2 out?'

Comment: Since the integral is with respect to a *different variable*, $t$, you can treat the $x^2$ as a constant and write the integral as $$x^2 \cdot \int_0^x sin(t^2)dt$$

Comment: So $f'(x)=x^2\sinx +2x\int_0^x\sin(t^2)~dt$. Is that correct?

Comment: Almost. Your first term should be $x^2 \sin (x^2)$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks @TheChaz

Comment: You really should think about the Bonus question though! It requires the chain rule...

Comment: Is the answer $3x^2sin9x^2+2x\int_0^{3x}sin(t^2)~dt$?

Comment: Yes! Good luck to you.